# Drush make: external command could not be executed

Tags: drush

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

php:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Drupal: not installed yet

drush status:

```
 PHP executable        :  /usr/bin/php                                 
 PHP configuration     :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini                        
 PHP OS                :  Linux                                        
 Drush version         :  6.0                                          
 Drush configuration   :
```

My .make file:

```
; This file was auto-generated by drush make
core = 7.x

api = 2
projects[] = drupal

; Modules
projects[] = addtoany
```

This is my error:

```
$ drush make hww2.make local.hww-master2.info
Beginning to build hww2.make.                                             [ok]
The external command could not be executed due to an application error.   [error]
drupal-7.42 downloaded.                                                   [ok]
The external command could not be executed due to an application error.   [error]
addtoany-7.x-4.11 downloaded.                                             [ok]
The external command could not be executed due to an application error.   [error]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Does running with `-v` or `--debug` provide any additional insight into the error?